# CSS doesn't apply to dynamically created text field

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic

I have created a dynamic text field for my form. Both the add and delete function works perfectly fine but when I applied CSS it won't work.
I'm a newbie in javascript and really appreciate if you could help me in figure it out. Here is the code:

```js
var counter = 1;
  var limit = 3;

  function showTextBox() {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      //var add = 'add' + (counter - 1) ;
      console.log(newdiv);
      //console.log(counter);
      var tr = document.getElementById(newdiv);
      console.log(tr);
      newdiv.id = 'add' + counter;
      var sample = newdiv.id;
      //console.log(sample);
      //console.log(newdiv.id);
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Option  <input type='text' >";
      //document.getElementById("newdiv").setAttribute("style", "borderRadius: 10px; borderColor: #777; cursor: text; height: 20px;");
      //newdiv.style.setProperty('border-radius', '10px', 'border-color', '#777', 'cursor', 'text', 'height', '20px');
      newdiv.style.paddingBottom = "10px";
      document.getElementById("tbhold").appendChild(newdiv);
      counter++;
  }

  function hideTextBox() {
      var add = 'add' + (counter - 1);
      //console.log(counter);
      var tr = document.getElementById(add);
      console.log(tr);
      tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
      counter--;
  }
```

```css
#option{
   font-size: 16px;
   text-align: center;
   top: 250px;
   padding-top: 50px;
  }
  #option > span{
   text-align: center;
   margin-left: 80px;
   top: 50px;
  }
  #tbhold > p > input{
   margin-left: 20px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-color: #777;
   cursor: text; 
   height: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="option">
    <span><strong>Name</strong></span>
    <div id="tbhold">
      <p>Option  <input type="text" name="c_field" id="c_field"></p>
     </div>
     <a href="javascript:showTextBox()"><span>+</span></a>&emsp;&emsp;<a href="javascript:hideTextBox()"><span>-</span></a>
   </div>
```

Comment: Is the error in the snippet also present in your original code? Or is it a mistake?

Comment: The code as posted can't possibly work, but probably your problem is that the CSS applies to `<input>` elements that are direct children of a `<p>` tag that is the direct child of an element with id "tbhold". It doesn't look like your function is trying to create such a structure.

Comment: I dont understand the upvotes sometimes. There is no error visible and on top of that, a non working snippet has been added.

Comment: newdiv is the div element u created, u dont need to get it again using .getElementById, u can use it directly like newdiv.innerHTML, newdiv.setAttribute, ..., after that u need to add it to the dom so it can appear, like doument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newdiv)

Comment: @Red see there was an edit...

Comment: Yes now its working. But wasn't at the time of my comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Input` isn't getting generated inside p so remove nesting of `p` tag

```js
var counter = 1;
  var limit = 3;

  function showTextBox() {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      //var add = 'add' + (counter - 1) ;
      console.log(newdiv);
      //console.log(counter);
      var tr = document.getElementById(newdiv);
      console.log(tr);
      newdiv.id = 'add' + counter;
      var sample = newdiv.id;
      //console.log(sample);
      //console.log(newdiv.id);
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Option  <input type='text' >";
      //document.getElementById("newdiv").setAttribute("style", "borderRadius: 10px; borderColor: #777; cursor: text; height: 20px;");
      //newdiv.style.setProperty('border-radius', '10px', 'border-color', '#777', 'cursor', 'text', 'height', '20px');
      newdiv.style.paddingBottom = "10px";
      document.getElementById("tbhold").appendChild(newdiv);
      counter++;
  }

  function hideTextBox() {
      var add = 'add' + (counter - 1);
      //console.log(counter);
      var tr = document.getElementById(add);
      console.log(tr);
      tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
      counter--;
  }
```

```css
#option{
   font-size: 16px;
   text-align: center;
   top: 250px;
   padding-top: 50px;
  }
  #option > span{
   text-align: center;
   margin-left: 80px;
   top: 50px;
  }
  #tbhold input{
   margin-left: 20px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-color: #777;
   cursor: text; 
   height: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="option">
    <span><strong>Name</strong></span>
    <div id="tbhold">
      <p>Option  <input type="text" name="c_field" id="c_field"></p>
     </div>
     <a href="javascript:showTextBox()"><span>+</span></a>&emsp;&emsp;<a href="javascript:hideTextBox()"><span>-</span></a>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript wont work because you need to load first the div before applying styles on it. See the modified code below

```
function showTextBox() {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var add = 'add' + (counter - 1) ;
    //console.log(newdiv);
    //console.log(counter);
    var tr = document.getElementById(newdiv);
    console.log(tr);
    newdiv.id = 'add' + counter;
    var sample = newdiv.id;

    newdiv.innerHTML = "Option  <input type='text' >";

    newdiv.style.setProperty('border-radius', '10px', 'border-color', '#777', 'cursor', 'text', 'height', '20px');
    newdiv.style.paddingBottom = "10px";
    document.getElementById("tbhold").appendChild(newdiv);
    document.getElementById(sample).setAttribute("style", "borderRadius: 10px; borderColor: #777; cursor: text; height: 20px; font-size:50px;");
    counter++;
}
```